# Using VBA, how to populate ComboBox values based on specific comlumn in an excel table

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Using VBA, I'm trying to build this sophisticated form to add new rows to an existing table.
I want to have this ComboBox that will list the values already exists in the one of the table's column.

I'm new to VBA. and I tried some Range/Selection and sort combinations with no lack so far...

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you're looking for.. It should get you started, Just adapt the Sheets and Range to your needs.

```
  Dim cmb as ComboBox
  Dim rng as Range

  Set cmb = Worksheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1

  'To fill based on range
  For Each rng in Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C300")
  Cmb.AddItem Rng.Value
  Next

  'To fill from table where ListColumns(N) is the specific column
  Set rng = Sheet2.ListObject(1).ListColumns(3).Range
  For Each rng in rng
  Cmb.AddItem Rng.Value
  Next

  Cmb.ListIndex = 0
```

***EDITED:***Chris is right, my original code had errors. Posted answer on way to work didn't have time to check. The code above works fine. Chris suggestion on just using .value to fill is quicker. I honestly didn't know you could do it like that.

Comment: -1 Sloppy code, doesn't compile: The correct reference to the table data is `Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange`.  Assumes combobox is an *ActiveX* combo on the sheet (may be true, but needs stating).  The loops are unnecessary, use `cmb.List = Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Value` instead.  If you do use AddItem, should use cmb.Clear before loading data, to remove any existing data in the combo.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your table column range,
Either you can insert your row in side the range
Or you need to first add row to table and resize your range
and pass that range pass to SetRng parameter,
userFormName is user form name,
ControlName is combobox name

```
Public Function FillRangeComboBox(userFormName As String, ControlName As String, SetRng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim ObjFormName As Object: Set ObjFormName = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(userFormName)
    Dim ObjControlName As MSForms.ComboBox: Set ObjControlName = ObjFormName.Designer.Controls(ControlName)

    ''set combobox value
    With ObjControlName
         .RowSource = SetRng.Address

    End With

End Function
```